# php and html not see new css elements when I run on localhost

Tags: php, html, css

When I change my project name to .php , my php page doesn't see new css element. When i change name to .html and after run my project directly to directory. This time my project see all css element. İf run my project on localhost , this time same  and doesn't see new css elements.

I tried everything , close xampp and browser so same. After restart my computer and then same

My css import code;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="adminstyle.css" />
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Try using an absolute reference to the CSS file.

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: Instead of `adminstyle.css`, use `/path/to/adminstyle.css`. Granted, this will change depending on where the code is deployed.

Comment: Try clearing your cache with a hard-refresh. `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `R`.

Comment: I solved this problem and i download chrome and try, its run successful. Why return to me problem yandex this time? it would not give this error in advance

Comment: Thanks @ObsidianAge, what is the cause of this error?